# Div not reacting to margin after a floated div

Tags: html, css

I have two main divs `service-display-box` and `service-contact`.

`service-contact` is not setting properly after `service-display-box`, which has floated `div`s inside of it.

Let me first state that I am using `clear: both;` after the floated `div`. In addition, `service-contact` is reading the `margin`, but it is starting it halfway into the `service-display-box`.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. It works in the snippet, but not on my page.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
#service-display-box {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
#service-display-box-container {
  padding: 135px 15%;
}
.service-item-box-img-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px 10%;
}
.service-item-box-img {
  margin: 50px 0;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 4px #BEBEBE;
}
.service-item-box-img.left {
  float: left;
}
.service-item-box-img.right {
  float: right;
}
#service-contact {
  margin: 225px auto 75px auto;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}
#service-contact a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#service-contact-button {
  border: 1px solid #578570;
  background: #578570;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="service-display-box">
  <div id="service-display-box-container">
    <div class="service-item-box" id="service1">
      <h1 class="service-item-title">DEMOLITION</h1>
      <h2 class="service-item-description">
                <p>We continues to build a strong legacy in the dismantlement industry because of our proven ability to complete projects ranging in nearly any size”</p>
                <p>We have played a valuable role in the demolition of numerous industrial facilities throughout the region including chemical, steel mills, energy generation, tire, and automotive. These structures demand skillful understanding along with proper tools and equipment to be safely brought down.</p>
                <p>Commercial demolition is essential in the redevelopment process. The region has allowed us to complete numerous commercial projects. We are able to perform interior, selective, and full demolition services to our clients.</p>
                <p>Residential demolition is a fundamental ability. We provides turnkey services to the public, the government, and development entities.</p>
            </h2>
      <div class="service-item-box-img-container">
        <img src="images/service/demo/demo1.jpg" alt="Eslich Wrecking Company Demolition and Wrecking Services" class="service-item-box-img left">
        <img src="images/service/demo/demo2.jpg" alt="Eslich Wrecking Company Demolition and Wrecking Services" class="service-item-box-img right">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div id="service-contact"><a href="contact"><span id="service-contact-button">CONTACT US</span></a>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: not sure what the output you are trying to achieve here, but just me

Comment: I just want the button to be lower.... that is all. I want it to clear the float and then be able to be positioned like normal.

Comment: but your layout in "demolition" section is kinda messy right now, unclear what kind of layout will be having, and I see those 225px after all

Comment: The Demolition section should not have any effect in what I am trying to receive. The contact button appear regardless of what service tab is clicked on. That is why it is nested outside of the `service-item`box`'s. How would my media query that you mention override the main one? The only thing that changes is the margin. I do not change the `clear: both` to `clear: none`. I don't understand how that matters.

Comment: see this: https://i.snag.gy/N0JT3D.jpg

Comment: @dippas I added an image to my question of what I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the jQuery in this line:

```
$('#service'+item_number).show().siblings().hide();
```

Which making  your `<div class="clear"></div>` to be styled as `display:none` due to be a siblling of your  `.service-item-box` divs,

To fix this is saying that the `div`s with class `.service-item-box` are the only one to be affected, so will be like this:

```
$('#service'+item_number).show().siblings('.service-item-box').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: Thanks again for all of the help, I really appreciate it1

Answer (score 2):

You're not clearing the floats correctly:
The easiest way to expand an element with floated elements inside him is to add `overflow: hidden;`. So go ahead and give

```
.service-item-box-img-container { 
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: overflow hidden it is not the best way to clear floats

Comment: Never said it is. I said it's the easiest and in this case it works perfectly.

Comment: *The easiest way to expand an element with floated elements inside him is to add overflow: hidden;*   you said

Comment: easiest != best . It is indeed the easies in my opinion.

Comment: This only works for the service options that have multiple rows of images.

Answer (score 1):

Your div that was setting `clear: both` also has `display: none` which essentially renders it useless. Getting rid of the `display: none` moved the button down 225px for me

Comment: I don't see where I have it set to display none?

Answer (score -1):

hope i understood the question.

add `{ float:left;width:100%}` to `.service-contact` and the margin will be calculated correctly

also add `{ float:left;width:100%}` to `.service-top`